# Rails 3 - Export to Excel with gridlines

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What can I add to this method to force full gridlines in Excel export?

```
  def export_invoices
    headers['Content-Type'] = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="Invoices.xls"'
    headers['Cache-Control'] = ''
    @invoices = Invoice.all
    render :layout => nil
  end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, lots of things going on here that I don't think make sense.  The line

```
@invoices = Invoice.all
```

results in SQL like `SELECT "invoices".* FROM "invoices"` -- the `*` means you want all columns from the table, and the `.all` means you want all the invoices, not just one.  Unless the contents of the table is a single column binary type, I cannot see this working, since Excel's file format is vendor-specific binary (I think!).

Are you using some gem like paperclip or other to handle saving files?  Unless you are manipulating the actual excel data from within Rails (perhaps with a gem that knows how to do this), either the file was saved with gridlines on, or not.

Comment: Um, well, when I click on the Export to Excel link, it exports what I want from the invoice table to an Excel file, which I can open or save as appropriate.  The only thing is that it hides all the gridlines, so I wanted those shown by default upon opening the file.

Comment: Ah, perhaps the columns and rows of the invoice table represent the cells of data to be exported.  It is possible to export in an XML format, so perhaps that's what's going on, see http://airbladesoftware.com/notes/excel-export -- but it's the MS format that determines whether gridlines appear, so you'll need to figure that part of the application out.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/HowToExportToExcel) describes how you can format your Excel file using XML.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly, you are looking to style the output in excel. To do that you need to actually generate an office open XML document, not dump CSV with application headers.

Have a look at these two gems

http://rubygems.org/gems/axlsx

http://rubygems.org/gems/acts_as_xlsx

They should give you what you want.